# Translation check そろそろキツい and だかんねえ

Tags: translation, colloquial-language, onomatopoeia, interpretation

Context. Characters A and B have just gotten defeated by younger character C. And it has been about a year or so since they last met.

> A: 若い子の相手は、そろそろキツいわー
>
> B: 年だかんねえ、あたしたちも。

My problem in general with A and B is that they seem to tent to really colloquial language, especially A.

But anyway, first of, the problematic bit is そろそろキツいわー. I think キツい is きつい which was for some reason written using katakana. わー is likely some sort of untranslatable exclamation. My problem is そろそろ + きつい since it isn't excatly logical to say slowly formidable. So as of now I'm translating it as:

> This young girl is steadily becoming formidable…

but I'm not 100% certain.

For the B's dialogue, 年だかんねえ is problematic. After some digging I was able to figure out that 年だかんねえ= 年だからねえ. So I'm thinking that she MIGHT be saying that their defeat and growth of C is because it's been a year. あたしたち is probably there to add that it's been a year for them too (since they were retired for that time). ねえ is just there to make it rhetorical. SO for now the translation is:

> It’s been a year for us too.

So basically the question is am I right? Where am I wrong? And is there any special meaning behind using katakana instead of hiragana for キツ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A: 若{わか}い子{こ}の相手{あいて}は、そろそろキツいわー
>
> B: 年{とし}だかんねえ、あたしたちも。

Where to start?  I'll be honest.  You're having a harder time than you seem to think with these lines.

「そろそろ」, in this context, means "***gradually***".

「キツい」 here means ***"tough", "difficult", "hard"***, etc.  The reason for the katakana use is that it is used for the colloquial/slangy meaning of 「きつ
い」, which orignally means "tight".  The use of katakana for that purpose is extremely common.

> わー is likely some sort of untranslatable exclamation.

Precisely.

More importantly, the subject of the first sentence is 「相手」 and not 「若い子」.  The subject is "***facing young kids***" and not "young kids".

On to the second line..

「年{とし}」 here means "***old***" and not "year".  Trust me, you will encounter this usage over and over.

「だか**ん**ねえ」 is the Kanto colloquialism for 「だか**ら**ねえ」 as you guessed.  The more colloquial native speakers get, the more ん's and small っ's they use.

Thus, my own TL would be:

> "It's gradually getting tough to face young(er) kids."
>
> "'Cause we're getting old, eh?"

Comment: When you mentioned that I didn't notice that facing young kids and not young kids is the subject, I think there was an audible light on sound in my mind. Yeah I was waaay off on that one. 
For the second one, I did internally consider it one of options that B thinks it's due to their age, but eh, it didn't really click for me. So thanks for that too.
And these two REALLY like their colloquialisms which actually can make them more impenetrable than an obligatory Kansai user in the group.