# What is the meaning of すっかんね at the end of a sentence

Tags: particles

> いにしえの書物には魂が メチメタこもってっからひとを呼び寄せたり乗り移ったりすっかんね。

It means "Books from ancient times are full of spirits. So I guess they can possess people". But I don't know the function of すっかんね in the above sentence.

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55332/45489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just するからね spoken in a very slangy way (consistent with the rest of the text).